# Plot Frequency of Data in ggplot2

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have a data frame that looks like the following:

```
threshold <- c("thresh1","thresh3","thresh10","thresh3","thresh3", "thresh10")
expression <- c("expressed", "expressed", "expressed", "depleted",  "expressed", "depleted")
data.frame("Threshold" = threshold, "Expression" = expression)
```

I would like to generate a histogram of counts of the different thresholds, bucketed by the expression.

I have attempted to do so using `geom_bar()`, but I not want the data stacked. Rather, I want the different categories (depleted, enriched etc...) to be represented in their own bars.

```
ggplot(final_nonexpressed, aes(x = threshold, fill = expression))+geom_bar(width = 0.5)
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: use `geom_bar(width = 0.5, position = "dodge")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the help page for `?geom_bar()`, specifically the `dodge` argument. For example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, fill = factor(drv)))
g + geom_bar()
```

[image]

```r
g + geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>